# Custom excel sort/order?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

So I've gone through a whole lot of sorting which isn't relevant to the question,
but for elaboration I'm getting 10 results out of 14. These results will be in order from 1-14 as I get them through my sort.

I'll get back a column of 10, of all the active numbers in this case 
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14] 
And essentially I need this to be sorted in a way that it prioritizes 1-10 and fills out the ones missing with 11-14 like so:
[12, 2, 14, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

```
|What I get|What I want|
|----------|-----------|
|2         |12         |
|4         |2          |
|5         |14         |
|6         |4          |
|7         |5          |
|8         |6          |
|9         |7          |
|10        |8          |
|12        |9          |
|14        |10         |
```

All the sorting happens dynamically and the solution needs to be able to handle that as well. The range can be anything from 1-14. I get 20 columns that all need to dynamically sort with this logic.

I'm hoping my question and what I'm trying to do makes sense. It's my first time posting so I hope I structured it correctly. 
**[EDIT] It doesn't seem like the table formatting is going through? Changed it.**

Comment: Please, format properly your question.

Comment: In my preview the table is formatted correctly, but when I submit the change/edit, it turns out like this.

Comment: So you want to filter 1-10, if the values is lost from 1-10 ten use 11- 14 filled the missed values in 1- 10. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Lee Yes, that's correct. Essentially using 11-14 as buffer numbers to replace within the 1-10.